# Multi-column input box only lets me select items in first column

Tags: ms-access

I am making an Access entry form to add items to a database. I want to display a list of items and be able to select multiple items from the list. Since there will be a lot of items in the list, I want to use multiple columns to save vertical space. The problem is, when I do this, it will only let me select items in column 1--the selection highlight goes all the way across the screen as shown. I CAN select multiple items, but only items in the first column. [image showing multi-column box with selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIgoE.png)

A similar thing happens when I use check boxes--in this scenario only the first column of items actually displays check boxes--items in other columns cannot be selected. I have played with the various column settings and bound column stuff, but I can't get this to work. Can anyone tell what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: That's working as intended. Only the index column is what you want while the other columns are to aid the user in selecting the row. You could specify a hidden column which is a concatenation of the visible columns if desired as the index column.

Comment: Combobox doesn't work the way you want it to. Each line is a single item. Can't be otherwise. Line is selected, not a column.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense now and explains why things I thought would fix it didn't.